# QueryPath or DOMDocument for editing large XML files?

Tags: php, xml, openxml, domdocument, querypath

I'm trying to edit a large XML file (extracted from an Excel .xlsm file) using PHP, and I was wondering which is best (regarding performance) : QueryPath or PHP's DOMDocument ?

The file weighs at least 8 MB, and contains around 400k lines (when formatted).

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryPath is basically just a wrapper around `DOMDocument`. It adds relatively little overhead to a bare `DOMDocument` object. For accessing and writing operations -- things like `attr()`, `append()`, and such, there should be no noteworthy performance difference.

But then it comes to the big issue: Finding stuff.

Traditionally, traversing a `DOMDocument` is done by either "walking the tree" or using `DOMNode->getElementsByTagname()`. This preforms relatively well if you're willing to write the code.

Querying with QueryPath 2.x will be sorta slow on a document that size unless you use very specific selectors (e.g ':root>foo>bar>baz').

However, QueryPath 3.x, which is about to go into Alpha1 is many, many times faster when querying large objects. Doing `qp('foo')` is as fast as XPath... which brings me to the last option.

Then there's the built-in XPath processor that also comes with PHP's libxml support. That might give you better performance if you're doing a large XML document, since it is executed at C speed instead of at PHP speed. But you will have to write XPath expressions, which are (IMHO) sort of a pain.

So the bottom line:

- Basics: Either one will do.
- Modification: Either one will do.
- Lots of traversing:

  - DOMDocument will make you traverse manually.
  - QueryPath 2.x is slow
  - QueryPath 3.x is much faster
  - XPath is fastest... but it's XPath

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since I wasn't aware of QueryPath 3.x, I ditched the 2.2 version, and went with PHP's DOMDocument. The XML structure is pretty easy to understand, and doesn't go very deep (maximum 5 levels deep in my case). So it's not a big pain to use...